# Unexpected Behavior When Modifying PE Section Characteristics on Windows 11

Tags: portable-executable, windows-11, sections, binaries, characteristics

I am currently working on a technical book and exploring the characteristics of sections within a Windows Portable Executable (PE) file. Specifically, I have been experimenting with a Python script to modify the characteristics of sections like the .text section in a sample executable.

As expected, revoking the 'execute' characteristic of the .text section led to a segmentation fault when trying to run the program. However, I encountered an unexpected result when I revoked the 'read' characteristic: the program still executed without any issues.

Is this known behavior in Windows 11, or could it be a bug?

I tried rebooting the VM after changing section permissions to verify.

Any insights or advice would be much appreciated!!
[Modified Section Permissions still executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgOLI.jpg)
[ObjDump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWk9.jpg)

Comment: I'm pretty sure x86-64 (which I assume is likely your processor's architecture) doesn't support non-readable virtual memory pages, so Windows cannot make .text non-readable. It's only a bug in Windows if MSDN states that the PE loades shouldn't accept that, but I don't think it's the case

Comment: @abel1502, The processor is x86-64, however, it is compiles with mingw32-i686-gcc

Comment: Memory paging depends on the actual processor, but it would've been the same for x86 regardless

Comment: for additional elaboration, I removed the read permission from .rdata and got a seg fault. I marked the .rdata section as executable and did not get a segfault.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's more interesting then. Maybe the Windows docs state somewhere that execute imply read?

Comment: That's my current theory, I just have not found any supporting docs